Send a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) push notification from Android application to subscribed topics using REST API without using any backend server
I am trying to send the push notification from application to all subscribers who subscribed the topic. User is subscribe to topic at registered time. Then allow admin to send notification from app to all subscribers. for that purpose added the following lines of code.
 // Construct the message
    val message = JSONObject()
    message.put("to", "/topics/Notification")
    message.put("notification", JSONObject().apply {
        put("title", "Padwa")
        put("body", "${binding.edtNotification.text}")
    })

    //send notification on button click
    binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding.edtNotification.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please insert some text message to send Notification",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            // Send the message
            //var url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/"
            //val url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
            val url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dreamfitness-6e82d/messages:send"
            val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, message,
                { response ->
                    Log.d("TAG", "Notification sent successfully: $response")
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Notification sent successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                { error ->
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error sending notification: $error")
                }) {
                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                    headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer server key" // Replace with your server key
                    return headers
                }
            }

            // Add the request to the RequestQueue
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest)
        }
    }

I am bit confused whether i am going in right way or not. And also not able to get the server key  due to new updating of firebase console. Any help is appreciated to guide and resolve this.

FCM requires that you send messages from a backend, otherwise you have a big security problem because you will leak your service account credentials (the line where you have "Bearer server key" in your app.  Don't do this.

No issues bcz only ower is going to used it for keeping records of his client .

OK, so what's the problem with what you have now?  Please edit the question to describe what isn't working the way you expect, along with any errors you're getting.  Right now, your post is just saying "it doesn't work" without any sort of explanation.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.
